# string to date - in C# [ "Mon Jan 13 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)"]

Tags: c#, datetime, date-format

I have a situation in which I am receiving date as a string in following format.

**"Mon Jan 13 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)"**

I need to convert it to following format in c# (Either date/string) for further processing

`YYYY-MM-DD (2014-01-13)`

```
Convert.ToDateTime(SelectedData)
```

Above code thorws following error:

```
'Convert.ToDateTime(SelectedData)' threw an exception 
       of type 'System.FormatException' System.DateTime {System.FormatException}
```

Any suggestions?

I can't change the format in which I am receiving the date
Best Regards.

Comment: Will you always receive the same exact format?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're going to need to use `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "Mon Jan 13 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)",
    "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'K '(GMT Standard Time)'",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

after parsing the date you can then send it out your way:

```
date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Here's an [Ideone](http://ideone.com/fnIyr5) to prove it.

Comment: This worked:                        var date = DateTime.ParseExact(s,
                                   "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'K '(GMT Standard Time)'", 
                                   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //Tx guys for this quick help

Comment: @user2739418, I've edited my answer with your modified format. I'm glad we could be of assistance!

Answer (score 9):

[`Convert.ToDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses standart date and time formats and this is not a [standart `DateTime` format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If your `GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)` is defult in your string, you can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead like;

```
string s = "Mon Jan 13 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(s,
           "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)'",
           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Output will be;

```
2014-01-13
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/4GUyNm)</kbd>.

For more information, take a loo at:

- [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`The "K" custom format specifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#KSpecifier)

Answer (score 3):

```
string date = SelectedData.Substring(4, 11);
string s = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MMM dd yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: This worked excluding all of the above, for me. Thanks @Plue :-*